# How can i hide image widget when keyboard pops in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, keyboard, widget, hide

Hello guys i need your help , I just want to hide the image widget when the keyboard pops,
but when i click the textfield and open a keyboard it keeps closing, can you help me with this i attach my code thank you !

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ovsursadmin/screens/authentication/login_card.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: ExactAssetImage('assets/bg-admin.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue[900].withOpacity(0.1), BlendMode.dstATop),
          )
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child : Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
// this code i want to fix it keeps closing the keyboard when pops
                MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? Container() : Image.asset('assets/urs.png',
                height: 100,
                width: 100,),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0,),
                Text('Admin Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                Text('Online Voting System', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                LoginCard(),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

[This is my problem it keeps closing when you click the text field and open the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZvlf.gif)

Comment: pop by means close or open in  your case?

Comment: yes open the keyboard ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

**Add Dependency:**

dependencies:
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.6

**Code:**

```
   bool _isKeyboardOpen = false;
    @protected
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
        onChange: (bool visible) {
        setState(() {
          _isKeyboardOpen = visible;
          });

        },
      );
    }
```

**Use code in build widget Like:**

**Option1:**

```
_isKeyboardOpen ? Container() : Image.asset('assets/urs.png',
                height: 100,
                width: 100,)
```

**Option2:**

```
  if(!_isKeyboardOpen)
      Image.asset('assets/urs.png', height: 100, width: 100,)
```

Comment: The keyboard keeps closing when clicking the textfield, just like the image above, i think i t refreshing the widget that's why it closing the keyboard?

Comment: it closes immediately when open a keyboard

Comment: Add Option 2 in that case

Comment: still closing the keyboard when clicking the textfield sir ! thankyou

Comment: @NehryDedoro: Can you provide some more code, with your current code I can not  able to reproduce your issue.